# Display content related to only those button it is clicked in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have three buttons in HTML, `orders` and `products` and `supplier`. I want when the user clicks `orders` order is being shown, when the user clicks `products`, the product is shown, and the name of the supplier when it is clicked.

```js
function changedata(parameter){
    if(parameter==0){
        document.getElementById('myorders').style.fontSize="25px";
    }
    else if(parameter==1){
        document.getElementById('myproducts').style.fontSize="25px";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('mysupplier').style.fontSize="25px";
    }
}
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="changedata(0)">ORDERS</button>
<button class="button" onclick="changedata(1)">PRODUCTS</button>
<button class="button" onclick="changedata(2)">SUPPLIER</button>
<div id="myorders">
    <p>Laptop, Earphone</p>
</div>
<div id="myproducts">
    <p>Earphone, smart watch</p>
</div>
<div id="mysupplier">
    <p>Amazon, E-kart</p>
</div>
```

But it won't hide data and serve my need, I'm a beginner in web development, looking for kind help to show data only when the corresponding button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are slightly easier ways to connect each `div` to its corresponding button, and one of them is to use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). We can add a data attribute to each button the text of which matches the `id` of its corresponding `div`.

(I'm assuming that when you click on one button all the other `divs` are hidden, and only its `div` shows.)

This example uses more modern JS techniques but I'll guide you through them, comment everything, and provide documentation at the end. You don't have to understand everything here but you're probably going to bump up against these things eventually, so you might as well take a look at them now.

Here's a rundown of how this all works:

1. Remove the inline listeners from the buttons. Modern JS uses `addEventListener`.
2. Wrap the buttons in a container. What we're going to use is a technique called [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/). Instead of attaching listeners to every button we attach *one* to the container and this captures any events that "bubble up" the DOM from its child elements. We can then call a function when a child element is clicked.
3. The function does a few things. First it checks to see if the clicked element was actually a button. Then it hides all the "panels" by removing a class called "show" from them ("show" sets the element's `display` to `block` - initially all panels have their display set to `none`). Then based on the id from the button's data attribute it forms a selector with it, and we use that to target its corresponding `div` and apply the "show" class.

```js
// Cache out buttons container, and all of the panels
const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');
const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');

// Add an event listener to the buttons container
buttons.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// When a child element of `buttons` is clicked
function handleClick(e) {
 
  // Check to see if its a button
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {

    // For every element in the `panels` node list use `classList`
    // to remove the show class
    panels.forEach(panel => panel.classList.remove('show'));

    // "Destructure" the `id` from the button's data set
    const { id } = e.target.dataset;

    // Create a selector that will match the corresponding
    // panel with that id. We're using a template string to
    // help form the selector. Basically it says find me an element
    // with a "panel" class which also has an id that matches the id of
    // the button's data attribute which we just retrieved.
    const selector = `.panel[id="${id}"]`;

    // Select the `div` and, using classList, again add the
    // show class
    document.querySelector(selector).classList.add('show');
  }
}
```

```css
.panel { display: none; }
.show { display: block; }
.button { text-transform: uppercase; }
.button:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: #fffff0; }
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button data-id="myorders" class="button">Orders</button>
  <button data-id="myproducts" class="button">Products</button>
  <button data-id="mysupplier" class="button">Supplier</button>
</div>

<div class="panel" id="myorders"><p>Laptop, Earphone</p></div>
<div class="panel" id="myproducts"><p>Earphone, smart watch</p></div>
<div class="panel" id="mysupplier"><p>Amazon, E-kart</p></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)
- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [Template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Thank you so much for the very insightful answer. when I run code snippet here, it works. But when in vs code, I put the first part of code inside <script> .. </script> second part inside <style> .. <style> and the third part inside the <body> ..</body> of my html file and run it on browser, only i can see the buttons, when I click the buttons, it does not show any data. why?

Comment: Where is your script tag? Is in the `<head>`? If so move it to just before the `</body>` - the DOM must load before the script can run. Alternatively use [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer).

Comment: yeah scrip is in head tag, https://gouravsingh675.github.io/test_repo/

Comment: Just move the script to just before `</body>` and you'll be golden.

Comment: It is still not working sir, edited on Github too, https://github.com/gouravsingh675/test_repo/blob/main/index.html

Comment: I should have said _just before_ the `</body>`. Make sure the script [comes _after_ your HTML markup](https://pastebin.com/vZunFMAz).

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much, got to learn many things from your super insightful answer.

Comment: @Andy I think  this method won't work inside Django template, like putting the script before </body> isn't a very standard approach.

Comment: Where does the question mention anything about Django? @Satya

Comment: Your answer is perfectly fine, i just meant this isn't a generalized approach. like it won't work in Django html template, it may work with some modification, i'm not sure. that's it. Thanks!

Comment: It's just native JS, and is a very generalised approach for the question. It won't work in React, Vue, Angular either. I've never used Django, don't use it, and never will. I'm really struggling to see what your point is.

Answer (score 3):

Try giving each element a default value of display:none in your css, as such -

```
#myorders,
#mysuppliers,
#myproducts {
  font-size: 25px;
  display: none;
}
```

This will select each element and hide them right away.

Then, when a button is pressed, you can use

```
document.getElementById('___').style.display = 'block';
```

to then show that element.

Here is the final product:

```js
function changedata(parameter){
    if(parameter==0){
        document.getElementById('myorders').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else if(parameter==1){
        document.getElementById('myproducts').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('mysupplier').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

```css
#myorders,
#myproducts,
#mysupplier{
font-size: 25px;
display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="changedata(0)">ORDERS</button>
<button class="button" onclick="changedata(1)">PRODUCTS</button>
<button class="button" onclick="changedata(2)">SUPPLIER</button>
<div id="myorders">
    <p>Laptop, Earphone</p>
</div>
<div id="myproducts">
    <p>Earphone, smart watch</p>
</div>
<div id="mysupplier">
    <p>Amazon, E-kart</p>
</div>
```

If you would like to have the element toggle between hidden and shown on each button press, I recommend toggling a class with javascript, as such:

```js
function changedata(parameter){
    if(parameter==0){
      document.getElementById('myorders').classList.toggle('active');
    }
    else if(parameter==1){
    document.getElementById('myproducts').classList.toggle('active');
    }
    else{
    document.getElementById('mysupplier').classList.toggle('active');
    }
}
```

```css
#myorders,
#myproducts,
#mysupplier{
font-size: 25px;
display: none;
}
#myorders.active,
#myproducts.active,
#mysupplier.active{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="changedata(0)">ORDERS</button>
<button class="button" onclick="changedata(1)">PRODUCTS</button>
<button class="button" onclick="changedata(2)">SUPPLIER</button>
<div id="myorders">
    <p>Laptop, Earphone</p>
</div>
<div id="myproducts">
    <p>Earphone, smart watch</p>
</div>
<div id="mysupplier">
    <p>Amazon, E-kart</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the kind answer, Upvoted. I want to ensure when you click on one button all the other divs are hidden, and only its div shows. How can we do it.